# Запрет передачи нецелочисленных параметров

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Как строго запретить передавать в шаблонную функцию аргументы нецелочисленных типов? Нашёл такое решение:

```
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>>
void foo(T t) {

}
```

Но его можно хакнуть, указав второй шаблонный тип явно:

```
f<double, void>(3.14);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может просто так пойдет?

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T t) {
  static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "Integer required.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Например:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T t) {
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value> g();

}
```

или там

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T t) {
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value> * g;

}
```

Ну, т.е. как-то "нехорошо" использовать `enable_if_t`, где требуется присутствие типа.

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T t) {
    using nafig = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>;

}
```

Или вот, как делали до `enable_if_t`:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T t) {
    int g[std::is_integral<T>::value];

}
```

Comment: необязательно использовать `enable_if_t`, есть другое решение?

Comment: Можно воспользоваться старым фокусом - объявить массив размером `std::is_integral<T>::value`...

Comment: а зачем нам `is_integral` в массиве? + не очень хочется выделять лишнюю память

Comment: Тогда не переживайте, что кто-то хакнет ваш код :)

Answer (score 1):

Это не хак, а выстрел себе в ногу. Это как `#define private public`. Вроде компилируется и может быть даже работает, но ничего хорошего из этого точно не выйдет.

Некоторые люди даже придерживаются точки зрения, что достаточно написать так:

```
/// \bief Функция
/// \param[in] t Аргумент
/// \warning Допускаются только целочисленные аргументы
template <class T>
void foo(T t) {

}
```

И этого будет достаточно.

Но если отвечать на ваш вопрос, можно спрятать `enable_if` в теле функции:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T t) {
    typedef typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type Dummy;

}
```

PS: Однако, если человек твердо задался целью передать вам в функцию `double`, его ничего не остановит:

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace std{
    template<>
    struct is_integral<double>{
        static const bool value = true;
    };
}


template <typename T>
void foo(T t) {
    typedef typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type Dummy;

}

int main()
{
    foo(3.14);
}
```

Так что рекомендую вам сильно не переживать по поводу "хаков". Пока есть препроцессор и специализация шаблонов, вы не сможете защитится на 100%

Comment: Фокус со специализацией `is_integral`, по крайней мере в VC++, не проходит.

Comment: @Harry, у меня нет визуалки под рукой, чтобы проверить. Какая ошибка? [Этот](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/) онлайн компилятор нормально все прожевал.

Comment: Ага, хохма в том, что у меня был включен `<iostream>`. Если его выключить, то проходит. Словом, нужно, чтоб этот `is_integral` создавался первым...   Впрочем, поскольку все эти шаблоны идут в исходниках, можно не извращаться, а просто подредактировать сам исходник :)

Comment: @Harry, я добавил `iostream` и у меня все работает:) Дайте код, который у вас не компилируется для опытов

Comment: http://vpaste.net/lLbX0

Comment: @Harry, ну да, визуалка и правда не компилирует. Но это не беда, пока есть препроцессор безвыходных ситуаций не бывает :) http://cpp.sh/7cugm

Comment: Воистину так :)